# Run-time error '-2147024773 (8007007b)' when macro saves to .pdf

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I have a code that is giving me the error in the title. It had been working perfectly and suddenly, it started giving this error.

```
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="S:\AA\as-tss\Inter_Setor\1_HOTLINE_TÉCNICO_Compartilhado\Criação de Conteúdo\Dicas" & "\" & Sheet8.Range("Q13").Value, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

The rest of the code has been suppressed for the sake of efficiency.
I have no clue as to what is causing this. It literally had been working fine up until today, and I have not changed a single character in this part of the code.

Any thought will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi, i just see two places where it can be wrong. Or  Sheet8,range("Q13").value is not valid as a file name, or you aren't selecting a sheet(s) when you do the .ExportAsFixedFormat. good luck

Comment: Did you delete any pages in your workbook? What is the value of `Sheet8.Range("Q13").Value`?

Comment: The error is `INVALID_NAME`. I'd suggest building the file name in a variable and checking the value with the debugger.